# TypeLoadException during serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-core

When I try to open [my custom visualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString#visual-studio-debugger-visualizer-for-expression-trees) on an expression tree in a .NET Core project (targeting 2.2), I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' was thrown by the custom visualizer component in the process being debugged.
>
> Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The following code (derived from the stack trace, at the end of the question) appears to have the same issue:

```csharp
// using System;
// using System.IO;
// using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
var stream = File.Create(Path.GetTempFileName());
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var data = new VisualizerData(expr); // serialized class with information about a given expression tree
formatter.Serialize(stream, data); // fails with the same exception
```

when the code is running in a .NET Core project, but uses a class (`VisualizerData`) from a referenced .NET Framework assembly (targeting 4.7.2); that assembly has references to WPF assemblies.

**How can I debug this issue? What might cause it?**

Note that there isn't any deserialization going on here; this is all while starting up serialization.

[Source code for `VisualizerDataObjectSource.TransferData(Object target, Stream incomingData, Stream outgoingData) in VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs:line 9`](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString/blob/master/Visualizer.Shared/VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs#L9)

---

Stack trace:

```
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationEvents.GetMethodsWithAttribute(Type attribute, Type t)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationEvents..ctor(Type t)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationEventsCache.<>c.<GetSerializationEventsForType>b__1_0(Type type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationEventsCache.GetSerializationEventsForType(Type t)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArrayMember(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo arrayElemTypeNameInfo, Object data)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, BinaryFormatterWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Boolean check)
   at ExpressionTreeVisualizer.VisualizerDataObjectSource.TransferData(Object target, Stream incomingData, Stream outgoingData) in C:\Users\Spitz\source\repos\zspitz\ExpressionToString\Visualizer.Shared\VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs:line 9
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebuggeeSide.Impl.ClrCustomVisualizerDebuggeeHost.TransferData(Object visualizedObject, Byte[] uiSideData)
```

Comment: The serialize and deserialize must be run with same classes and with same version of Net Library (maybe, object sizes can change in different version of net).

Comment: @jdweng This scenario used to work previously. I'm not sure at which point over the past few months this broke.

Comment: Probably when you either changed the classes or Net Library was updated.  Try serializing new data and then deserialize to make sure it works with current configuration.

Comment: @jdweng _The serialize and deserialize must be run with same classes and with same version of Net Library_, except that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization#binary-serialization-in-net-core) say this shouldn't be an issue -- _The defined set of types are guaranteed to be serializable between .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions and .NET Core 2.0 and later versions._

Comment: The documentations is referring to  same c# classes and same 4.5.1 and Core 2.0.  But not when you change your c# classes or using 4.5.0 and Core 2.0.

Comment: @jdweng I don't follow. The issue here appears to be in the `Serialize` method (based on the stack trace), not in the deserialization. The problem is not one of incompatibility between the serialization result and deserialization. Also, the results of the serialization aren't stored on disk; the point of the serialization is for data to cross the debugged/debugger divide, as is described [here](https://wrightfully.com/debugger-visualizer-for-nonserialized-types). Both serialization and deserialization happen each time the visualizer is started.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195932/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-jdweng).

Comment: Where is the data coming from that is used to fill the classes?  The binary serialize method simply takes the c# classes and creates a byte array (the byte array can be in a stream).  The error is coming from the VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs:line 9.  So there is an issued with the data source which is before any serializing actually occurs.

Comment: @jdweng [VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs line 9](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString/blob/master/Visualizer.Shared/VisualizerDataObjectSource.cs#L9) looks like this: `Serialize(outgoingData, visualizerData);`. `Serialize` is a static method on the base class of `VisualizerObjectSource`, part of Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll; it seems as though serialization starts there.

Comment: The link has 3 parameter : 1) The class object 2) The input data that fills the classes 3) The serialized ouput byte[] (stream).  You only have two parameters.

Comment: @jdweng _You only have two parameters._, Well yes, because `VisualizerObjectSource.Serialize` has multiple overloads, one of which takes only two parameters. Unless you're saying that the exception happens in line 7 which deserializes incoming data? The stack trace seems to imply differently.

Comment: Don't you need three parameters?  Where is the classes being loaded with data.  If you are using the two parameter overload you must be filling the classes in your code.  The serializer could be giving an error if the class object contains null data.  For example the serializer will give an exception if a DateTime object is null.  When I have exceptions like this I usually comment out objects in the class until the error goes away to find which item is failing.  Right now I'm questioning the two parameter overload.

Comment: @jdwang The `TransferObject` method has three lines. 1) Read serialization of options class into a new options instance. 2) Create a new instance of `VisualizerData` using the options class from step 1. 3) Serialize the `VisualizerData` instance into the outgoing stream. The stack trace seems to indicate the problem is in step 3. The source of `VisualizerData` and `VisualizerDataOptions` is [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString/blob/master/Visualizer.Shared/VisualizerData.cs).

Comment: @jdweng _the serializer will give an exception if a DateTime object is null_ Even if the property's type is `Nullable<DateTime>`? What about string fields, or fields of other reference types?

Comment: The c# error message are not very clear.  That is why I normally isolate serialize errors by commenting out code until I find the object that is causing the error.

Comment: @jdweng Please see my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56880549/111794).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that serializing a value type defined in the referenced .NET Framework assembly is at the root of the problem.

Using the following methods:

```
static (bool success, string failPath, string errorMessage) CanSerialize(object o, string path = "") {
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = File.Create(Path.GetTempFileName())) {
        return CanSerialize(o, path, formatter, stream);
    }
}

static (bool success, string failPath, string errorMessage) CanSerialize(object o, string path, BinaryFormatter formatter, Stream stream) {
    if (o == null) { return (false, path, "Null object"); }

    string msg;
    var t = o.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string)) { return (true, path, null); }
    try {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        return (true, path, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        msg = ex.Message;
    }

    List<(string, object)> values;
    if (t.IsArray) {
        values = (o as IEnumerable).ToObjectList()
            .Select((x, index) => ($"[{index}]", x))
            .Where(x => x.Item2 != null)
            .ToList();
    } else {
        values = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(fld => !fld.IsStatic)
            .Select(fld => ($".{fld.Name}", fld.GetValue(o)))
            .Where(x => x.Item2 != null)
            .ToList();
    }

    foreach (var (name, value) in values) {
        var ret = CanSerialize(value, path + name, formatter, stream);
        if (!ret.success) { return ret; }
    }
    return (false, path, msg);
}
```

the following `struct` definition:

```
[Serializable]
public struct EndNodeData {
    public string Closure { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

the following code:

```
var endnodeData = new EndNodeData {
    Closure = null,
    Name = null,
    Type = "int",
    Value = "5"
};
Console.WriteLine(CanSerialize(endnodeData));
```

prints out:

> (False, , Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.)

It would seem the problem is with this specific type, or value types in general.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the following message is refering to a NET Framework 4.0 element:

Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

The maximum NetFramework target you could use is defined by this element.

Comment: So, downgrade all the csprj .Net Framework versions in your solution

Comment: How can I figure out which dependency is using this version of the framework?