# TypeLoadException in .NET Core project during serialization of value type from referenced .NET Framework project

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-core

I have the following project dependency structure:

- `_visualizerTests.dotnetcore` -- **.NET Core 2.2**

  - `Visualizer.2019` --  **.NET Framework 4.7.2**

In the .NET Framework project, I have the following type defined:

```
[Serializable]
public struct EndNodeData {
    public string Closure { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to serialize this type in the .NET Core project:

```
var endnodeData = new EndNodeData {
    Closure = null,
    Name = null,
    Type = "int",
    Value = "5"
};
var stream = File.Create(Path.GetTempFileName());
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, endnodeData);
```

I get the following exception:

> **System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

Class types defined in the .NET Framework project serialize without a problem, as do value types defined in the .NET Core project.

**How can I resolve this?**

(This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56868801/111794).)

Deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, and deleting the solution's `.vs` folder doesn't help.

I've filed an [issue on the .NET Core repo](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2981).

Comment: What version of Net is your project properties listed as the Target? what version(s) of Microsoft.Net.Framework do you have installed?  Normally this issue occurs if a version of Net is not installed.  Depending on the version of Net you may need older versions of Net installed because Microsoft doesn't include older libraries in new releases.  For example in Net 3.5 you need to also install Net 2.0 because 3.5 does not have all the 2.0 libraries.  I suspect you have Net 4.7.2 but not 4.5. Net 4.5 I believe is accumulative of all older version for a 64 bit machine.Try target x86 instead of 64.

Comment: Look at datetime of the .exe files in the bin folder.  Make sure all exe have latest date.  I sometimes see people only compile the debug version and then try to execute an older version of the release.  Use clean before recompiling to make sure all the object get recompiled.

Comment: @jdweng All projects are currently targeting AnyCPU. Also, I've deleted the bin/obj folders, and the .vs folder; and run **Clean solution** then **Rebuild**. All this doesn't really explain why only value types should be affected.

Comment: You are serializing a linq anonymous type.  May be you need to NuGet package referenced here : https://sebnilsson.com/blog/convert-c-anonymous-or-any-types-into-dynamic-expandoobject/

Comment: @jdweng `EndNodeData` is not an anonymous type, and the use of `var` doesn't make it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has presumably been fixed in .NET Core 3, but until then, the following workarounds are available:

- Avoid auto-implemented properties; use full properties, or public fields instead. (In order to suppress the compiler warning, I used `[SuppressMessage("", "IDE0032", Justification = "https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2981")]` for this purpose.
- Define a custom `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute` in the same assembly or some common assembly.

[Feedback on the Roslyn issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2981#issuecomment-508549529)